# write and read from command line

Tags: vim, plugins, command-line, vimscript

How I can write something to vim command line and then read some input from it to plugin?
For example, I want to write choose "Choose search patter (1, 2, ... 0):". Then user presses "2", the plugin read receive it and do something. How make such interaction in vim plugin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your function:

```
call inputsave()
let p = input('Choose search patter (1, 2, ... 0):')
call inputrestore()
echom p "here you got userinput
```

for detail:

```
:h input()
:h inputsave()
```